# Execute an action before redirecting to the template in the confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, symfony, dialog, confirm

The first field is the title of critic, the second field is the content of critic. When I write something in the title field automatically creates the object Critic in the db. In this situation I have a new row with the new critic but in the fileld of content the value is null. In this situation appears a confirm dialog.

When the confirm dialog appears, what should I do to click the "ok" button and, apart from being redirected to the new template, executing the eliminarCriticaAction of the Controller.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
        if( ! $('#criTitulo').val() || ! $('#criContenido').val() ) {
            if ( ! $('#criTitulo').val() && $('#criContenido').val() ) {
                if(! window.confirm( 'Falta el titulo' )) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }               
            }
            else if ( ! $('#criContenido').val() && $('#criTitulo').val() ) {
                return confirm('Falta el contenido');
            }   
        }
    });
```

Delete action of Controller:

```
public function eliminarCriticaAction($pysStr)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pys = $em->getRepository('PYSBundle:Pys')->findPys($pysStr);
    $usuario = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $critica = $em->getRepository('UsuarioBundle:Usuario')->findCritica($usuario, $pys);

    if(!$critica) 
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("No hay ninguna crítica que borrar");
    }

    $em->remove($critica);

    $em->flush();

}
```

## EDIT

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var titulo = $('#criTitulo').val(), contenido = $('#criContenido').val();
    console.log(titulo);
    console.log(contenido);
    if ( ( titulo && !contenido ) || ( !titulo && contenido ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Link clicked !');
        if (window.confirm( 'Falta el titulo' )) {
            $.get(Routing.generate('eliminar_critica.' + $('html').attr('lang'), { "_locale": $('html').attr('lang'), "pysStr": $('section').attr('pelicula') }));
            window.location.href = $(e.target).attr('href');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear to me what the route to your delete controller is. I will assume "/Pys/{pysStr}" with route name "my_pys". Also your current "pysStr" should be available as variable in your twig template. Assuming in your display controller you put:

```
'currentPysStr' => $pysStr    (put this in the render method are argument)

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if( ! $('#criTitulo').val() || ! $('#criContenido').val() ) {
        if ( ! $('#criTitulo').val() && $('#criContenido').val() ) {
            if(! window.confirm( 'Falta el titulo' )) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                $.get({{ path('my_pys', {'pysStr': currentPysStr}) }})
            }
        }
        else if ( ! $('#criContenido').val() && $('#criTitulo').val() ) {
            return confirm('Falta el contenido');
        }   
    }
});
```

Then in your delete controller you will have the current PysStr and this controller will only be called when you press OK in the confirmation dialog.

The same as in your order question you have a choice if you want to put this script in a twig template or use a global variable. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035337/translate-the-jeditable-plugins-attributes/18035436#18035436 )

**EDIT:** (after chat)

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var titulo = $('#criTitulo').val(),
        contenido = $('#criContenido').val();
    console.log(titulo);
    console.log(contenido);
    // Requested: XOR
    // One of the values must be set, the other one must not be set
    if ( ( titulo && !contenido ) || ( !titulo && contenido ) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Link clicked !');
            if (window.confirm( 'Falta el titulo' )) {
                var ajax;
                var url = Routing.generate('eliminar_critica.' + $('html').attr('lang'), { "_locale": $('html').attr('lang'), "pysStr": $('section').attr('pelicula') });
                console.log(url); // This is just here for debugging purposes
                ajax = $.get(url);
                ajax.done(function() {
                    window.location.href = $(e.target).attr('href');
                });
            }
    }
});
```

Placing `window.location.href` in `done()` guarantees the request was made before the page refresh

`eliminarCriticaAction` should give a Response that everything went on (2**) response. 204 is appropriate like this:

`return new response('', 204); // 204: No Content`

Comment: Yeah, this code works fine, but what I am looking for is the deleteAction called when pressing the "ok" button rather than "cancel".

Comment: adjusted my answer, it should now trigger on OK, not cancel

Comment: I have just edited the question code. Now, when clicking the "ok" button, it effectively executes "else", and if I type console.log the message appears. But the delete function is not executed.

Comment: Check your symfony log files to see if your app get a request from the client.

Comment: It doesn't execute the action

Comment: That can happen if something is messed up with your routing or something else is wrong in the framework. Inspect your symfony dev.log in your app folder to see if there is a request at that time. Also it's good to inspect the network traffic with your browser (with for example firebug).

Comment: It is strange, the console.log appears in the console when I click the ok button but the `$.get(Routing...` line doesn't execute. In the browser's console nothing appears about this line, only the console.log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34839/discussion-between-benatespina-and-flip)

Comment: I'm trying to refinated the JS function and the error comes to " window.location.href = $(e.target).attr('href'); " Instead redirect a link route, redirected to http://filmboot.local/app_dev.php/es/user/pelicula/machete/undefined/ So I think the problem is in that line. The deleteAction doesn't have a return, that's a problem?

Comment: join the chat again. or open a new question.

Comment: Yes please close this question and start a new one because there is one question after another and posts have to keep edited this way. Your newest question is about jEditable getting the correct values.

Comment: The new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083258/jeditable-returns-the-old-values

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown). It gives you the possibility to use your routes in JavaScript as well.

After installing the bundle, modify your `Controller annotation`:

```
eliminar_critica:
    locales: { es: "/eliminar-critica/{pysStr}/", en: "/delete-critic/{pysStr}/" }
    defaults: { _controller: UsuarioBundle:Default:eliminarCritica }
    options:
        expose: true
```

After that you can use this code of JavaScript to access the route:

```
Routing.generate('eliminar_critica', { pysStr: 10 });
// will result in /eliminar-critica/10/

$.get(Routing.generate('eliminar_critica', { pysStr: 10 }));
// will call /eliminar-critica/10/ without redirecting your browser
```

For further reading you should read about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

---

In your JavaScript:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if( ! $('#criTitulo').val() || ! $('#criContenido').val() ) {
        if ( ! $('#criTitulo').val() && $('#criContenido').val() ) {
            if(! window.confirm( 'Falta el titulo' )) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                // insert this line: (optional add a callback)
                $.get(Routing.generate('eliminar_critica', { pysStr: 10 }));
            }
        }
        else if ( ! $('#criContenido').val() && $('#criTitulo').val() ) {
            return confirm('Falta el contenido');
        }   
    }
});
```

For a nice callback like

> Your Entity has been deleted!

Take a look at the jQuery `get()` [method here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Yeah, this code works fine, but what I am looking for is the deleteAction called when pressing the "ok" button rather than "cancel".

Comment: Updated my answer. Be aware that the JavaScript part has nothing to do with **Symfony2**.

Comment: I am already using the FOSJsRoutingBundle. I have just edited the question code. Now, when clicking the "ok" button, it effectively executes "else", and if I type console.log the message appears. But the delete function is not executed.

Comment: Check your console. What status message does the server return? Also try to add an `echo 1; exit;` in your `action` and see if it is returned.

Comment: what's your console output? Server response? Anything in the server logs?

Comment: It is strange, the console.log appears in the console when I click the ok button but the `$.get(Routing...` line doesn't execute. In the browser's console nothing appears about this line, only the console.log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34838/discussion-between-benatespina-and-byf-ferdy)

Comment: I'm trying to refinated the JS function and the error comes to " window.location.href = $(e.target).attr('href'); 
"
Instead redirect a link route, redirected to `http://filmboot.local/app_dev.php/es/user/pelicula/machete/undefined/`
So I think the problem is in that line. The deleteAction doesn't have a return, that's a problem?